# excel vba code error Block if without end if

Tags: excel

I get the subject error with this code. pls help. this code is for hiding n un-hiding a set of rows which are below a certain criteria

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$q$2" Then
    BeginRow = 8
    EndRow = 460
    ChkCol = 13

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value < Cells(2, 19) Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's with the extra `End Sub`?

Comment: you have two `End Sub` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the first

```
End Sub
```

*( the line before the `End If`)*

**EDIT#1:**

also replace:

```
$q$2
```

with:

```
$Q$2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
doing this doesnt autorun the code when the value of Q2 cell changes

Comment: @saurabh  See my **EDIT#1**